# Using WSUS APIs to get updates from microsoft server to local server

Tags: windows, wsus

I am planning to write an application using WSUS APIs, to get updates from Microsoft, can someone please suggest me some tutorials or links where I can find some sample code to get started, I have already referred to the APIs in MSDN, however is there some other place, where I can get some clarity so as how to get started?

Comment: It's a little unclear what you're looking for. Are you looking for the wire-protocol between the Windows Update client and the server, or are you just looking to automate using the Windows Update client?

Comment: WSUS is a product of microsoft, and they have also provided api's for the same, i want to create a application similar to WSUS of microsoft, using WSUS's apis,
Unfortunately i couldnt find any sources to refer.

Comment: Are you trying to re-make [WSUS Offline](http://download.wsusoffline.net/)?

Comment: Not WSUS offline, but WSUS server itself, actually I already have an application running on the windows server, I want to add a new module that application, that will act as WSUS server, download updates for me from Microsoft's site, so that the clients can access them from my server...

I dont want to use the WSUS product given by Microsoft...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More significantly, the API is only the interface to allow the console to talk to the service, or to allow a client to talk to the service, or to allow a downstream server to talk to the service. It is not the service itself.

Comment: this was my real confusion, i thought i could get all the functionality of WSUS by just using its API's and not installing it.. thanks,,

Answer (score 3):

The [[MS-WUSP]: Windows Update Services: Client-Server Protocol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc251937.aspx) is the canonical reference for the client/server protocol between a Windows client and a WSUS server. It's basically a SOAP API. I don't think you're going to find much in the way of sample code-- not too many people have tried to implement an alternative Windows Update client or server (to my knowledge, anyway). There are some sample client/server interactions in the docs, however.

Comment: Microsoft now provides what they call a `C# implementation (.NET Core) of the Microsoft Update Client-Server sync protocol` that can be found at https://github.com/microsoft/update-client-server-sync